# Dart: Incorrect interpretation of JSON String

Tags: json, dart

I'm trying to decode a zipped json file that is dropped (drag and drop file) into my Flutter web-app, however am having some challenges getting the correct text from the file.

For example, the file contains the following line:
"Cond\u00c3\u00a9 Nast"

This should be Condé Nast.
I am somewhat aware of character encoding, but this has me stumped.

This is currently how I'm unzipping, utf8 decoding and finally json decoding the file. I am using the Archive package to do the unzipping.

```
ArchiveFile theFile = otherFiles.first;
final fileString = Utf8Decoder().convert(theFile.content);
Iterable l = json.decode(fileString);
```

How would I go about printing the correct character from this input JSON file string? Is this an issue of incorrect encoding? Or Is it an issue with my implementation?

Comment: If you mean that the object you get back from `json.decode` is a `String` with `"Cond\u00c3\u00a9 Nast"`, then I think it's likely that the JSON file was encoded incorrectly when it was written. Can you check the bytes of `theFile.content`?   The UTF-8 code units for `é` is the sequence 0xC3, 0xA9, so it seems like your string somehow was double-encoded to UTF-8.

Comment: @jamesdlin I think you're correct on the incorrect encoding - even the json file itself contains "Cond\u00c3\u00a9 Nast" as a value. Are you suggesting that I try to get the bytes from theFile.content and then try to UTF-8 decode it? I believe that theFile.content are the bytes.

Comment: I meant that you should check if the incorrect bytes are already present in `theFile.content`.  The correct sequence of UTF-8 bytes would be 0xC3, 0xA9.  An incorrect sequence from double-encoding to UTF-8 would be 0xC3, 0x83, 0xC2, 0xA9.

Comment: I'm unsure how to go about converting the content to a list of UTF-8 bytes, as when I try to encode it I just get a list of integers. However, from what I've researched it does seem that the data was encoded incorrectly, as the file itself contains double-encoding sequences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in comments, I suspect that `theFile.content` was incorrectly encoded at some earlier step and that it was sent through a UTF-8 encoder twice.  You can verify that by opening the file in a hex editor and examining its bytes.  Alternatively, in Dart you can do `print(theFile.content);` or, if you prefer seeing byte values in hexadecimal, `print([for (var byte in theFile.content) byte.toRadixString(16)]);`.

If you don't have any control over whatever generated that file, you should complain to someone who does.  In the meantime, you can try to undo the damage by feeding your content through a UTF-8 decoder twice.  `utf.decode`/`Utf8Decoder().convert` expect a `List<int>`, so you can't just feed them the mis-encoded `String` directly.

```dart
void main() {
  var badString = 'Cond\u00c3\u00a9 Nast';
  var goodString = utf8.decode(badString.runes.toList());
  print(goodString); // Prints: Condé Nast
}
```